# Converting UDPRN codes as points

Tags: qgis, convert, latitude-longitude, address, united-kingdom

I have some address data that's given as [UDPRN codes](https://www.edq.com/uk/glossary/udprn/), and want to plot them as points in QGIS. Is there a way to convert these to lat/long or join to some existing dataset that can get me there? The only other address data in the set is postcode, but I want to get more specific than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive lookup is the Ordnance Survey's [AddressBase](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/addressbase.html) product. You could also use the Royal Mail's [Postal Address File (PAF)](http://www.royalmail.com/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/programmers_guide_edition_7_v5.pdf) but that is harder work.

Neither of these datasets is free as the government sold off our locations to the private sector some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

As @iant said, OS AddressBase is your best bet for plotting these (you only need the basic AddressBase product, not Plus or Premium).

Depending on how many you have, this might not be that expensive to purchase. The addresses can be sold per address.

Best to get in touch with an OS re-seller: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/partners/finder/selector.html